# Have to reload page for if statement to be parsed

Tags: php, html, session, authentication

First: Code!

**`loginform.html`**

```
<form action="" method="post" id="loginform">

                <h3>Login</h3>
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                <br>
                <br>
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                <br>
                <input type="submit" name="logsubmit" value="Login" class="registerbutton">
            </form>
```

**`login.php`**

```
<?php 
require_once("../resources/config.php");
require_once("../resources/library/dbconnect.php");

function checkUser($con) {

   if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $pw       = md5($_POST['password']);

$sql="SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' and pw='$pw'";

       $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
       $row    = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if ($result==true && $username == $row["username"] && $pw==$row["pw"]) {


            $_SESSION["logged_in"] = 1;
            $_SESSION["admin"] = $row["admin"];
            $_SESSION["username"] = $row["username"];
        }

        else {

        $msg = "Das war nichts! Passwort oder Username falsch? <br>".mysqli_error($con);
        unset($_SESSION["logged_in"]);

        }
    }
}
checkUser($connection);
header('location: ../public_html/index.php');
exit;
?>
```

**`index.php`**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Barstone</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.php" type="text/css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter:700&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
    <?php require_once("../resources/config.php");
          require_once("../resources/library/header_nav.php");?>
    <div class="pagewrapper">

        <div class="register-container">

            <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) || !isset($_POST['regsubmit']))           
            {require_once("../resources/library/registerform.php");}

             if (isset($_POST['regsubmit']) && $_SESSION['register_check']==true) {printf("Success! Welcome %s!",$_POST['username']);}

            ?>

        </div>


        <div class="login-container">
            <?php if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) { printf ("<form action='../resources/library/logout.php' method='post' id='loginform'><h3> Hello %s!                           </h3> Nice to see you!<input type='submit' class='logoutbutton' value='logout'>                                         </form>",$_SESSION["username"]);
       }?>
             <?php if (isset($_POST["logsubmit"])) {require_once("../resources/library/login.php"); 
                        }
else { if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {require_once("../resources/library/loginform.html");}}
                ?>

        </div>
        <div class="content">
        <?php require_once("../resources/library/articles.php");?>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**`relevant index.php part`**

```
    {printf ("<form action='../resources/library/logout.php' method='post' id='loginform'>
   <h3> Hello %s!</h3> Nice to see you!
   <input type='submit' class='logoutbutton' value='logout'>
   </form>",$_SESSION["username"]);}
    ?>

   <?php if (isset($_POST["logsubmit"])) {require_once("../resources/library/login.php");}
        else {if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) 
               {require_once("../resources/library/loginform.html");}
                 }?>
 </div>
```

**What this is supposed to do:**

If the user is not logged in, show the `loginform.html`.
If the login button got pressed, use the `login.php` to log the user in.

After someone has used the login-form to log in to the website, it displays a little welcome message and a new button for logout purposes.

**What this does:**

Displaying the login form works fine.

***After someone logged in, it displays nothing. But after reloading the page, the button is there and works fine.***

The `$_SESSION['logged_in']` variable is set with the login, but why does the page need another reload to interpret this statement correctly?

I admit that the way I do it isn't necessarily 'best practice' and I am open for any advice. Still learning. :)

For testing: http://hsturnierv2.pixelpioniere.net/public_html/index.php login as "test" with pw "test"

Comment: you should add the code from `login.php` and `login.html` to get correct answer

Comment: Added the code and will delete my comments.

Comment: do you have a `session_start()` anywhere in your code?

Comment: what does index.php contain ? how is it related to input.php ?

Comment: yep. on top of the index.php but maybe I forgot it in the login.php - gonna try this!

Comment: I did not see your edits, when creating my answer.. But for the sake of security you REALLY should escape your user inputs before inserting them in your database queries...

Comment: Ok found the issue and updated my answer. Check it out below...

Comment: As stated below: Thank you! After finishing here I will test this. Thank you very very much for the work you put in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most probably the fact that you have

`header('location: ../public_html/index.php');`

instead of:

`header('Location: ../public_html/index.php');`

in login.php. It should have a capital L. It doesn't and you get no redirection, thus the blank page ...

***UPDATE***

So you redirect ok but your script dies for some reason. It is not a logical error rather a fatal script error that kills your script before it can output anything more ...
Your code is:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) 
{ 
    printf ("<form action='../resources/library/logout.php' method='post' id='loginform'>
    <h3> Hello %s!</h3> Nice to see you!
    <input type='submit' class='logoutbutton' value='logout'>                                          
    </form>",$_SESSION["username"]);
   }
?>
<?php if (isset($_POST["logsubmit"])) 
{
    require_once("../resources/library/login.php"); 
}else 
{ 
    if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {require_once("../resources/library/loginform.html");
    }
}
?>
```

So i got it. When someone is actually logging in index.php requires a login.php which when done sends a relocation header and exits. But the output has already started! you have already half of the page out!
So the header issues an error (which is not displayed probably due to php.ini settings) and then exits. Therefore you get half a page.

You should change your index.php code to:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST["logsubmit"])) 
{
    require_once("../resources/library/login.php"); 
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Barstone</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.php" type="text/css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter:700&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
    <?php require_once("../resources/config.php");
          require_once("../resources/library/header_nav.php");?>
    <div class="pagewrapper">

        <div class="register-container">

            <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) || !isset($_POST['regsubmit']))           
            {
                 if (isset($msg)) echo $msg .'<br>';
                 require_once("../resources/library/registerform.php");}

             if (isset($_POST['regsubmit']) && $_SESSION['register_check']==true) {printf("Success! Welcome %s!",$_POST['username']);}

            ?>

        </div>


        <div class="login-container">
            <?php if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) { printf ("<form action='../resources/library/logout.php' method='post' id='loginform'><h3> Hello %s!                           </h3> Nice to see you!<input type='submit' class='logoutbutton' value='logout'>                                         </form>",$_SESSION["username"]);
       }else { if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {require_once("../resources/library/loginform.html");}}
                ?>

        </div>
        <div class="content">
        <?php require_once("../resources/library/articles.php");?>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This prevents output before header and also shows the error if you enter wrong credentials. Then you should also change your login.php file so that it doesn't redirect every time, rather only if the login was successful, like so:

```
<?php 
require_once("../resources/config.php");
require_once("../resources/library/dbconnect.php");

function checkUser($con) {

   if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $pw       = md5($_POST['password']);

$sql="SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' and pw='$pw'";

       $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
       $row    = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if ($result==true && $username == $row["username"] && $pw==$row["pw"]) {


            $_SESSION["logged_in"] = 1;
            $_SESSION["admin"] = $row["admin"];
            $_SESSION["username"] = $row["username"];
            $msg='OK';
        }

        else {

        $msg = "Das war nichts! Passwort oder Username falsch? <br>".mysqli_error($con);
        unset($_SESSION["logged_in"]);

        }
    }
    return $msg
}
$result = checkUser($connection);
if ($msg=='OK')
{
    header('location: ../public_html/index.php');
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: It's not that it displays a blank page. It's just that the container is not there.

Comment: You can test it here: http://hsturnierv2.pixelpioniere.net/public_html/index.php (user: test, pw: test)

Comment: please paste the code for index.php. What is its relation to input.php that you have pasted above ?

Comment: It's a typo, it should say index.php - gonna paste the whole file and fix this in my question

Comment: Wow. Thank you! I have no time to try this right now but I will after my appointment.

Answer (score 1):

Well what you are doing basically:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) 
    // output something
?> 
<?php 
if (isset($_POST["logsubmit"])) { 
     // process login with login.php
} else {
     if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        //display login form   
     }
?>
```

Okay what happens here...

1. User visits site for the first time. ( Is not logged in and has not submitted login form)

   $_SESSION['logged_in'] is not set and // output something not reached

   $_POST['logsubmit'] is not set and also $_SESSION ['username'] is not set
   so the login form is displayed
2. User submits Loginform
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] is not set and // output something not reached

   $_POST['logsubmit'] is set and login.php is called 
    If you have no output in login.php the page stays blank.
    I assume you set the session vars in login.php
3. User reloads the page after login
   $_SESSION['logged_in'] is set now -> you reach // output something

I personally would handle the login in a seperate file:

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    // redirect to login.php
}
?>
// here comes the content when user is logged in
```

in login.php:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['logsubmit']) {
         // handle login and redirect to page that needs login if successfull 
    }

    if($loginError) { // print login errors }

    // print login form 
?>
```

Edit: don't forget session_start()  ( In included files session_start() is not neccessary)

Comment: First: Thanks for this explanation. I will think through it and try it out. Afterwards I will tell you if it worked.